# Render a Complete HTML in a iframe using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, websocket

Is there any way to show the complete html of a separate page in a iframe? Other than by using an Iframe src change.

Comment: look into jquery's `.load()`

Comment: do u want to show html code or render html in a div ?

Comment: You won't need html,head and body tags again...Just take the html of that page and put inside that div

Comment: @Innovation i want to rendor html. which would be of seperate page. exactly like iframe but without using iframe

Comment: @ASHWANIKUMARSINGHBISEN learn about http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ you will find your answer here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use his approach to  dynamically changing the content of iframe

```
var localS = "content";
document.getElementById('output_iframe1').src = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + escape(localS);
```

The vairable local can have any kind of html

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery Ajax call You can pass specific page URL and on success ajax you can set data in specific div like below

```
$('#specific-div').html(data);
```

Comment: probably cors will block what he wants to achieve

Comment: also u can use .append method of jquery to append html to respective div